# PFSense not getting WAN IP but Ethernet Adapter has one (Hyper-V)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, pfsense

we have a Hyper-v machine running on WS2012R2 Datacenter Machine.

Our modem is in bridge mode. Our office Mikrotik is currently getting a WAN IP address just fine. However, we want to move over to PFSense again since we had easier OpenVPN setup along with other more advanced features and control.

For some reason PFSense is only getting the local IP from the modem in bridge mode. Not sure why.

EDIT:
The Mikrotik will have a fully working public IP address being passed off from the modem and at the same time I can get a public IP address to the physical NIC on the server. However, passing the public IP to the Hyper-V machine seems to be the issue.

This is PFSense 2.3.2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your ISP might be the cause**

If you haven't already, try **fully resetting the modem according to your ISPs instructions**. I've seen this same problem before where the **ISP will not hand out an IP to a server with a different MAC address** than what was previously seen on the bridge.

If I recall correctly, I had to unplug the modem for a long time then reconnect, but it was years ago. Best to check with your ISP. *Every time I switched a modem from one computer to another, it was the same thing...*

**Alternativately**

If it is possible, have the PFSense server use the same MAC as the Mikrotik. This wouldn't be my first choice though. Actually, I don't think I would do it.

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Interface_Settings#MAC_Spoofing

***I hope this helps because it's simple and easy to fix! Good luck.***

Comment: This I fully agree with as I have seen this in real world production. I'll try this and some side tricks regardless. However, the part that throws me off is that I can have a fully working Mikrotik and still get an IP address to the physical MAC on the server at the same time (different public IP addresses).

Comment: To expand on this as the answer. The vNIC needed to have the pNIC MAC addressed cloned to it and then it took the public IP address.